# Find an example of vector spaces V/U isomorphic to V where U a subspace of V.

Tags: linear-algebra

So we have to find an example of vector spaces $V$/$U$ $isomorphic$ $to$ $V$  where $U$ a $subspace$ of $V$, we found a trivial solution where

$U := \{0\}$

but we weren't allowed this solution.  We were given the hint to use

> The direct sum $F[x] \oplus F[x]$ is isomorphic to $F[x]$.

we've spent a while on this, anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your favorite field $k$; and take the vector space $V=k^{(\Bbb N)}=\langle e_1,e_2,\ldots\rangle$, that is, this is a vector space of countable dimension over $k$. Of course, $k[X]$ does the same job. Then $ \langle e_1\rangle$ is a subspace, and $V/U\simeq V$.